# I cannot build a apk of my flutter project it tells me to upgrade my Kotlin version when I upgrade it I get more errors and when I solve them more com

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-build

I tried to make the apk of my flutter project but I couldn’t due to these errors which tells me to degrade to 1.5.1 but the suggestion of the flutter tells me to upgrade from 1.9.0 . I have tried both if I upgrade I get more and more errors as I try to solve them more appear and if I degrade the version 1.5.1 is not found so what do I do here:

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Awan\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\open_file-3.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\crazecoder\openfile\OpenFilePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 2568 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "iconsax.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1292372 to 11776 bytes (99.1% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
e: D:/Task/catalyst-mobile-app/build/barcode_scan2/.transforms/73c842728169587c247dc2f12742aece/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/barcode_scan2_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Task/catalyst-mobile-app/build/flutter_image_compress_common/.transforms/005418f1be5a75b1a5caf31303d73645/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/flutter_image_compress_common_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Task/catalyst-mobile-app/build/fluttertoast/.transforms/01f2138fef00cf230a725c448f354028/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/fluttertoast_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Task/catalyst-mobile-app/build/in_app_update/.transforms/3a93027dd9de51846e80de9b99ca1d1c/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/in_app_update_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Task/catalyst-mobile-app/build/libphonenumber_plugin/.transforms/59933ab16b91f834740f0751ef78bf86/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/libphonenumber_plugin_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Task/catalyst-mobile-app/build/otp_autofill/.transforms/4d459b0405b164745c693a2d802be258/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/otp_autofill_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Task/catalyst-mobile-app/build/qr_code_scanner/.transforms/a4375c8dcbad965fd7d26b5329702039/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/qr_code_scanner_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/399a19a2b46f1f4a14c90de111e09329/transformed/appcompat-1.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/appcompat_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1fa8649bc742cb87490e876ed7773310/transformed/jetified-activity-1.7.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/47c101f40a453bbe62197eb8b6ff4013/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/980f872b8e91e37773c95d19f03231d4/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/53ef862c37e4fb499658d8120adeb021/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/940a5190bd86b286ed21f39f12376a61/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/98e80985b7e56cff6245ac3f02aad2ba/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/619acf38d3c867d6d2cde74c2e473ee9/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/21fd899e9a36793822d016fbf732d685/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.1/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.1.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5dce752f4ba3d3bd3dfa69f9d691d5ef/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.7.1/920472d40adcdef5e18708976b3e314f9a636fcd/annotation-jvm-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/66e4f2a31cd72f0157e03b1cdc712a05/transformed/jetified-annotation-experimental-1.3.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/annotation-experimental_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Awan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.9.0/cd65c21cfd1eec4d44ef09f9f52b6d9f8a720636/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          814.4s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update D:\Task\catalyst-mobile-app\android\build.gradle:                                   │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to fix this issue by upgrading the ex.kotlin value in build.gradle

Go to android -> build.gradle

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.21'
```

or

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.21'
```

Both versions worked for me

I am using gradle version 8.2 in graddle -> wrapper -> graddle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-all.zip
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Hi. where you looks  dependencies flutter version <-> kotlin version <-> gradle version?
docs or websites, please say any sources